# Make Singleton class in Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, singleton, multiprocessing, metaclass

I create Singleton class using **Metaclass**, it **working good in multithreadeds** and create only one instance of MySingleton class but in multiprocessing, it creates always new instance

```
import multiprocessing

class SingletonType(type):
    # meta class for making a class singleton
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            return cls.__instance
        except AttributeError:
            cls.__instance = super(SingletonType, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            return cls.__instance

class MySingleton(object):
    # singleton class
    __metaclass__ = SingletonType

    def __init__(*args,**kwargs):
        print "init called"


def task():
    # create singleton class instance
    a = MySingleton()


# create two process
pro_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=task)
pro_2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=task)

# start process
pro_1.start()
pro_2.start()
```

**My output:**

```
init called
init called
```

I need MySingleton class **init** method get called only once

Comment: Why do you need metaclasses here?

Comment: I use metaclass for make class singleton in above code I create "SingletonType" metaclass and MySingleton is singleton class

Comment: Processes unlike threads do not share context (they each create copy of it when forked). This is where you should look into IPC if you want to exchange data between processes.

Comment: Native objects don't get shared between processes (due to reference counting).

Comment: @TomWyllie: not the first time people just wanting singletons come up with metaclasses. Some one coming from another language probably wrote a popular documentation suggesting this pattern. I am not usually in favor of beating up people, but in this case I wonder...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each of your child processes runs its own instance of the Python interpreter, hence the `SingletonType` in one process doesn't share its state with those in another process. This means that a true singleton that only exists in one of your processes will be of little use, because you won't be able to use it in the other processes: while you can [manually share data between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), that is limited to only basic data types (for example dicts and lists).

Instead of relying on singletons, simply share the underlying data between the processes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing
import os


def log(s):
    print('{}: {}'.format(os.getpid(), s))


class PseudoSingleton(object):

    def __init__(*args,**kwargs):
        if not shared_state:
            log('Initializating shared state')
            with shared_state_lock:
                shared_state['x'] = 1
                shared_state['y'] = 2
            log('Shared state initialized')
        else:
            log('Shared state was already initalized: {}'.format(shared_state))


def task():
    a = PseudoSingleton()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # We need the __main__ guard so that this part is only executed in
    # the parent

    log('Communication setup')
    shared_state = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
    shared_state_lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    # create two process
    log('Start child processes')
    pro_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=task)
    pro_2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=task)
    pro_1.start()
    pro_2.start()

    # Wait until processes have finished
    # See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25456494/857390
    log('Wait for children')
    pro_1.join()
    pro_2.join()

    log('Done')
```

This prints

```
16194: Communication setup
16194: Start child processes
16194: Wait for children
16200: Initializating shared state
16200: Shared state initialized
16201: Shared state was already initalized: {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
16194: Done
```

However, depending on your problem setting there might be better solutions using other mechanisms of inter-process communication. For example, the [`Queue` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) is often very useful.

Comment: but  i  create two instance of  PseudoSingleton class "a" and "b " and try to print  a is b it return False that mean PseudoSingleton  is not exactly Singleton class i always get new instance

Comment: As I said, you cannot share object instances between processes. This means that you will have at least one separate instance of your class in each child process. These cannot share their internal state (their attributes) but they can use a separately defined shared state (`shared_state` in my example). That way, your instances won't be true singletons but will nevertheless behave like one (because they operate on the same, shared data).

Comment: can I reinitiate all variable of  PseudoSingleton class, mean can I manually set or reset the shared_state_lock lock